# html form not posting from javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a html form that posts the data to a php file for processing, on this form there is a dynamically produced combo box that is produced from a php file using javascript. The combo box displays and functions fine when the page is loaded but when the form is submitted the value from this box isn't posted.

the JavaScript function is

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("selSubCat").innerHTML = "";
        return;
     } else { 
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         } else {
             // code for IE6, IE5
             xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                 document.getElementById("selSubCat").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
         }
         xmlhttp.open("GET","getSubCats.php?Cat="+str,true);
         xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

The html is

```
    <td >Category:</td>
      <td > 
        <select name="Cats" onchange="showUser(this.value)" ><?    

        $qryCats="SELECT * FROM tblCategories";
        $resCats=mysql_query($qryCats,$dbMain);
        while($rowCats = mysql_fetch_array($resCats)){
        echo "<option value='".$rowCats['Name']."'>".$rowCats['Name']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td >Sub Category:</td>

    <td  id="selSubCat"> 
    </td>
    </tr>
```

And the php file:

```
    <? 
    include("dbconfig.php");
   $cat=$_GET['Cat'];

    $qryCats="SELECT * FROM tblSubCats WHERE Parent='" .$cat. "'";
        $resCats=mysql_query($qryCats,$dbMain);
        if ($numrow=mysql_num_rows($resCats)>0){
            echo "<select name='subCats'>";
        while($rowCats = mysql_fetch_array($resCats)){
        echo "<option value='" .$rowCats['Name']. "'>" .$rowCats['Name']. "</option>";
        }

        echo "</select>";
        }
        else{
            echo " There are no sub categories ";
        }
    ?>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, I can't figure out why everything else apart from the subcategory is posted

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: Thanks for the advise Quentin, I do plan on changing everything to mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `name` attribute. In `HTML` its `Cats` but in your code you are using `$_GET['Cat'];` 
It should be

```
$cat=$_GET['Cats'];
```

Comment: Hi, the php file is getting the Cat variable from the javascript not the html select

Comment: I dont find any errors with the code. Did you watch console for any errors?

Comment: there is no errors in the error log, it posts the Cat select ok but doesn't post the subCats one from the added php code

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had a table on the html page which the form was inside. I swapped the tags around so that the table is inside the form and the dynamic fields post just fine. Not sure why having a form within a table stopped these from posting but at least it works now.